# Gerrit trigger can't see my SSH Keyfile on Windows

Tags: gerrit-trigger

Gerrit trigger returns
"C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.ssh\id_rsa" does not exist.

However the file exists, Jenkins can clone repos using it.
This is on Windows server 2016

Comment: Is your process running elevated? Is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 64-bit elevated running under local system account. I copy/pasted the key into C:\.ssh\id_rsa and now Gerrit trigger is able to see it...Test connection return "Success" but on top i see The connection could not be established! Check your settings and the Gerrit server...And server status is red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first i had to move the key inside C:\ so Gerrit trigger can see it...
Second i had to restart Jenkins because even if i click save the configuration is not saved...
Im using it also on Ubuntu never had such problems there.